# Prove that n! = O(n^n)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, big-o

How can I prove that n! = O(n^n)?

Answer (score 26):

I assume that you want to prove that the function `n!` is an element of the set `O(n^n)`. This can be proven quite easily:

Definition: A function `f(n)` is element of the set `O(g(n))` if there exists a `c>0` such that there exists a `m` such that for all `k>m` we have that `f(k)<=c*g(k)`.

So, we have to compare `n!` against `n^n`. Let's write them one under another:

```
n!  = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3) * ... * 3 * 2 * 1
n^n = n *  n    *  n    *  n    * ... * n * n * n
```

As you can see, the first line (`n!`) and the second line (`n^n`) have both exactly `n` items on the right side. If we compare these items, we see that every item is at most as large as it's corresponding item in the second line. Thus `n! <= n^n`.

So, we can - look at the definition - say, that there exists `c=1` such that there exists `m=5` such that for all `k>5` we have that `k! < k^k`, which proves that `n!` is indeed an element of `O(n^n)`.

Comment: To formalize this, you could easily turn it into induction.