# How to calculate the running time of this algorithm?

Tags: big-o

For fun I wrote an anagram generator. It takes some input word or phrase and rearranges the letters in different combinations to generate a new word or phrase. For example, if you enter "cat and dog", it will return things like "can dad got" or "ant cog dad".

A friend asked what the running time was, and I realized that I wasn't sure how to calculate it in this case. At startup, I read in a list of words (a dictionary). In my case it's about 200,000 words (it's the standard unix /usr/share/dict/web2 dictionary). That doesn't really factor into the running time as that's a one-time thing at app startup and it takes well under a second to read in and index the dictionary.

When the user enters a word, the application searches the dictionary for a list of candidate words. A word is a candidate if it contains only a subset of letters from the input word or phrase. Generating the candidates is an insignificant part of the process and can be ignored for now.

Then it starts searching. It chooses the first word in the list of candidates. Next it removes the letters of that word from the remaining letters in the input string. It then searches the candidates for any words remaining that contain only a subset of the newly reduced input string. It then recurses with the new reduced input word and reduced candidate list. It repeats this until there are either no candidates left, or the input string is all used up.

So it may start with 100 candidates it has to search. It chooses one and after removing any others with the same letters, there could be 90 left, or there could be 50 left, or there could be 10 left, so when we recurse, there's a different number left to search each time. This is why I'm having trouble understanding the running time.

If we never removed any words from the list, it would be O(n!) where n is the number of candidates. But since we aggressively trim the list on each iteration, it works out to far less than n!. For example, one phrase I tried generates over 4,000 candidates, and ends up finding over 600,000 combinations. It only takes about 30 seconds to do so on a recent notebook computer (utilizing only a single core), so clearly it's not O(n!).

In order to understand the running time, would I need to have some statistics about how much the list of candidates gets trimmed on average with each iteration or something like that?

I was thinking that if each iteration removed 10 candidates from the list, then we'd have something like this for a 100 candidate list: 100 * 90 * 80 * 70... Or more generally, n * (n - 10) * (n - 20) * (n - 30)... In the case of a 100 candidate list that would work out to O(n^10 - a*n^9 - b*n^8 ...).

Have I calculated that correctly, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: By the time you get to the `O()` of something, there is only one thing inside. You look at what happens to the terms when n gets very large. In your case, if you expect to eliminate m candidates on every attempt, your largest term would be `n^(n/m)`. Not sure what that simplifies to - it is less than `N!` but more than any `N^n` where `n` is a fixed integer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that the running time depends on the length of the input: `O(m)`. If a user enters a very long phrase that contains all letters of the alphabet many times:

> A quick brown fix jumps over the lazy dog; a quick brown fix jumps over the lazy dog; a quick brown fix jumps over the lazy dog, ...

your algorithm will consider the full dictionary (of size `n`) in the first `O(m)` iterations, so the running time is `n^O(m)`.

Here, the statement `n^O(m)` is rather weak even though it's correct: the exact running time might look like `n^0.01m` or `n^0.1m`; you may consider both smaller than `n^O(m)`, but you cannot find exactly which factor there is (it depends on the structure of English language), so `n^O(m)` here means "exponential running time in worst case; algorithm won't finish for large values of `m`".

Of course, you are probably interested in the running time for small values of `m`. If you assume `m<20`, it's pretty clear that the running time is O(n^20); you may consider this a better estimation than `O(n!)` or `O(n^(n/10))`.

To get better estimates, one would have to consider the structure of the dictionary; the running time depends really strongly on the dictionary. For example, if all words in the dictionary contain at least 2 letters (not sure about that), the running time can be estimated as `O(n^(m/2))`.

Anyway, the big-O notation doesn't seem to fit this problem in any useful manner.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! You're absolutely right that it's going to depend on the length of the input word or phrase as well, and also on the statistics of the English language.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction. Consider the only highest degree of the polynomial you get upon evaluation. So in your case:
`n*(n-10)*(n-20)*...10`

will give `(n)^(n/10)`.

So the running time of your algorithm is `O( (n)^(n/10) )`.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999448/prove-that-n-onn) for better understanding of running time.

Answer (score 0):

If average length of a candidate is `k`, and the source phrase is such that all candidates are removed only one by one, then the complexity will be O((n/k)!).

If initial number of candidates is `M`, and each step removes `s` words from the list of candidates, then the complexity is O(M * (M-s) * (M-2s) * ...) = O((M/s)! * s<sup>M/s</sup>).

In the worst case, you still have O(n!).

But, well, `n!` is what one could expect for such a task. I suppose most optimizations should be performed at the code that searches and removes candidates.