# Why n!=O(n^n) while log(n!)=Θ(log(n^n))

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

It can be proved that `n!=O(n^n)` by consider that `n!=n*(n-1)*...*2*1` while `n^n=n*n*n*n...*n`.
However, `log(n!)=Θ(nlogn)` and `log(n^n)=nlogn=Θ(nlogn)`.
I guess log is an Increment function so it should not change the relationship. How does this happen?

Comment: Better fit on https://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @ThomasJager   I think it is correct that n!=O(n^n)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999448/prove-that-n-onn

Comment: TL;DR `2 ln n = ln n²`

Comment: n!=O(n^n) simply because n! <= n^n. You probably meant big theta here too.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Just removed the "time-complexity" tag.

Comment: In the future, make sure to read the descriptions of tags, to make sure that they match what you're describing, that tag completely changes the field of the question. I've removed my comments, since they no longer apply, but I'd now consider this completely off-topic, since it doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess log is an Increment function

Whatever that means, it is not enough to preserve relative order of growth.

A simple example: *n²* grows strictly faster than *n*, but *ln n² = 2 ln n* grows at the same rate as *ln n*.

Answer (score 4):

n<sup>n</sup> grows faster than n!, but when you apply the log to both sides, the difference stays within a constant factor.

For comparison, consider that n<sup>3</sup> > O(n<sup>2</sup>), but log n<sup>3</sup> = 3 log n = Θ(log n<sup>2</sup>) = Θ(2 log n)

Comment: You mean *Θ(log n^2)* instead of *Θ(n^2)*?